# How to replace a special character in required position in a string in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How a can I replace a special character in a required position in xslt?

here is my xml:

```
<block4>

    <tag>
        <name>5</name>
        <value>accnt number
              Name
              Address1
              Address2
              Address3</value>
    </tag>
</block4>
```

Here is my current xslt logic:

```
<xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '5']">
            <xsl:variable name ="del50k" select ="(translate(substring-after(value,'&#13;'),'&#13;','~'))"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(value,'&#13;'), ',',$del50k)" />
        </xsl:for-each>,<xsl:text/>
```

output getting for my logic :

```
accnt number,Name~Address1~Address2~Address3,
```

but required output was

```
accnt number,Name~Address1 Address2 Address3,
```

The tidle separator should be in between `name` and `address1` only, `address` should follow with normalized space.

Can any one help me sort out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work!

```
<xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '5']">
    <xsl:variable name ="del50k" select ="concat(substring-before(substring-after(value,'&#13;'),'&#13;'),'~',substring-after(substring-after(value,'&#13;'),'&#13;'))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(value,'&#13;'), ',',$del50k)" />
</xsl:for-each>,<xsl:text/>
```